# Set language of a text document in a VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a Visual Studio Code extension where I try to open a
virtual editor:

```typescript
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(vscode.Uri.parse(previewSchema + ":" + path))

context.subscriptions.push(extractHibernateLogCommand, vscode.Disposable.from(
    vscode.workspace.registerTextDocumentContentProvider(previewSchema, hibernateExtractorProvider)
));
```

Those documents are always language:plain-text. Is it possible to change this programmatically to "SQL" to have the correct highlighting?

[Full code](https://github.com/GreenRover/hibernate-log-analyser/blob/master/src/extension.ts#L49)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution by myself:

```typescript
let options: Object = {
  content: string,
  language: "sql"
};

vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(options).then(doc => {
  vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc, vscode.ViewColumn.One);
}, err => {
  vscode.window.showErrorMessage(err);
});
```

A solution when using `TextDocumentContentProvider` seems not to be possible.

[The commit with my change](https://github.com/GreenRover/hibernate-log-analyser/commit/d163fe8772121e024c5b0da830906e0c2bf9b2d8)

Answer (score 6):

[Since VSCode 1.28](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_change-the-language-of-a-text-document) (September 2018), it's also possible to set the language mode for a document *after* it has been created using [`languages.setTextDocumentLanguage()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages.setTextDocumentLanguage):

> Set (and change) the [language](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextDocument.languageId) that is associated with the given document.
>
> *Note* that calling this function will trigger the `onDidCloseTextDocument` event followed by the `onDidOpenTextDocument` event.

Here's a simple example that opens a document containing `{}` and sets the language to JSON:

```ts
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument({content: "{}"}).then(document => {
    vscode.window.showTextDocument(document);
    vscode.languages.setTextDocumentLanguage(document, "json");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the Command Palette (View->Command Palette)
run "Configure language specific settings"
In the Select Language drop down there should be a setting for SQL

Comment: The easiest to do it manually is to use the switch in bottom bar. But i want to do it automatically